# How can I correctly restore a PST file?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2011

I recently restored a .pst file to outlook. The restore works fine but it creates a separate Inbox after this restore other than the "Personal Inbox"

How can I move this 2nd inbox to the "Personal Inbox"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Outlook as the user, and then use the File > Import and Export > Import from another program or file > Personal Folder File (.pst) > etc..., and then choose "Import items into the same folder in: Mailbox - John Smith".